# How do I only select images using reddit json?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a list of images from a specific reddit and send them to the user randomly. Is there a way to only get the json that lists a url?

I try to just get to this path down below, but it ends up throwing an error sense it is a nested array

```
  "kind": "Listing",
  "data": {
    "modhash": "2l53o1urucfcc06e46b02a400997e1d810b258af76c74bce9d",
    "dist": 25,
    "children": [
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "thumbnail": "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/AihwJOuW0jmGvdJqd71rVCQCA7nJYc4KoyclJttNn_c.jpg",
```

I want it to return a random image from the huge array. again my attempts threw in error about formatting the parser

every post is in the array of children, I want to access the lot of thumbnails and list them
I get the json from reddit.com/r/pics/top.json
I use request

```
console.log(parsedData["data"]["children"]...)
```

I do not know how to get past that to data without throwing an error

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? How is this JSON data structured?

Comment: What are the fields in each child? Is it a JSON dict that only has kind, data and thumbnail?

Comment: Put up the "every post" bit; along with an example of how you reduced it down to the current example.

Comment: The real json is much much longer but that are all the children objects until thumbnail, but this is just one post and not a series of the,

Comment: Here is the full JSON: https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/top.json  I want every thumbnail or Image sources listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parsedData.data.children.forEach(imageUrl => {
   console.log(imageUrl.data.thumbnail)
})
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was that simple, you are a legend sir.